# Lisp, Error: Comma not inside a backquote. [file position = 762]

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, allegro-cl

I've been following the [instructions](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/lisp/doc/install.html) to install coding examples for Lisp but have been getting the error "Comma not inside a backquote" when trying to load the file "aima.Lisp" using Allegro CL.

This is the code for the file (unedited code [here](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/lisp/aima.lisp)):

```
;;;  -*- Mode: Lisp; Syntax: Common-Lisp -*- File: 

aima.lisp

;;;; Vendor-Specific Customizations

#+Lucid (setq *warn-if-no-in-package* nil)

;;;; A minimal facility for defining systems of files

(defparameter "C:\Users\Aaron\Lisp\" 

(truename "~/public_html/code/") ; <<<<<<<< Edit this 

<<<<<<
  "The root directory where the code is stored.")

(defparameter *aima-binary-type*
  (first (list   ; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Edit this 

<<<<<<<<<
       #+Lispworks system::*binary-file-type*
       #+Lucid (first lucid::*load-binary-pathname-

types*)
       #+Allegro excl:*fasl-default-type*
       #+(or AKCL KCL) "o"
       #+CMU "sparcf"
       #+CLISP "fas"))
  "If calling aima-load loads your source files and not 

your compiled
  binary files, insert the file type for your binaries 

before the <<<<
  and load systems with (aima-load-binary NAME).")

(defconstant *aima-version*
  "0.99 AIMA Code, Appomattox Version, 09-Apr-2002")

(defparameter *aima-system-names* nil
  "A list of names of the systems that have been 

defined.")

(defstruct aima-system
  name (requires nil) (doc "") (parts nil) (examples nil) 

(loaded? nil))

;;;; The Top-Level Functions:

(defmacro def-aima-system (name requires doc &body parts)
  "Define a system as a list of parts.  A part can be a 

string, which denotes
  a file name; or a symbol, which denotes a (sub)system 

name; or a list of the
  form (subdirectory / part...), which means the parts 

are in a subdirectory.
  The REQUIRES argument is a list of systems that must be 

loaded before this 
  one.  Note that a documentation string is mandatory."
  `(add-aima-system :name ',name
            :requires ',requires :doc ',doc 

:parts ',parts))

(defun aima-load (&optional (name 'all))
  "Load file(s), trying the system-dependent method 

first."
  (operate-on-aima-system name 'load-something))

(defun aima-load-binary (&optional (name 'all))
  "Load file(s), prefering binaries to source."
  (operate-on-aima-system name 'load-binary))           



(defun aima-compile (&optional (name 'everything))
  "Compile (and load) the file or files that make up an 

AIMA system."
  (operate-on-aima-system name 'compile-load))

(defun aima-load-if-unloaded (name)
  (let ((system (get-aima-system name)))
    (unless (and system (aima-system-loaded? system))
      (aima-load system))
    system))

;;;; Support Functions

(defun add-aima-system (&key name requires doc parts 

examples)
  (pushnew name *aima-system-names*)
  (setf (get 'aima-system name)
    (make-aima-system :name name :examples examples
              :requires requires :doc doc 

:parts parts)))

(defun get-aima-system (name)
  "Return the system with this name.  (If argument is a 

system, return it.)"
  (cond ((aima-system-p name) name)
    ((symbolp name) (get 'aima-system name))
    (t nil)))

(defun operate-on-aima-system (part operation &key (path 

nil) (load t)
                    (directory-operation 

#'identity))
  "Perform the operation on the part (or system) and its 

subparts (if any).
  Reasonable operations are load, load-binary, compile-

load, and echo.
  If LOAD is true, then load any required systems that 

are unloaded."
  (let (system)
    (cond
     ((stringp part) (funcall operation (aima-file part 

:path path)))
     ((and (consp part) (eq (second part) '/))
      (let* ((subdirectory (mklist (first part)))
         (new-path (append path subdirectory)))
    (funcall directory-operation new-path)
    (dolist (subpart (nthcdr 2 part))
      (operate-on-aima-system subpart operation :load 

load 
                  :path new-path
                  :directory-operation 

directory-operation))))
     ((consp part)
      (dolist (subpart part)
    (operate-on-aima-system subpart operation :load 

load :path path
                :directory-operation 

directory-operation)))
     ((setf system (get-aima-system part))
      ;; Load the required systems, then operate on the 

parts
      (when load (mapc #'aima-load-if-unloaded (aima-

system-requires system)))
      (operate-on-aima-system (aima-system-parts system) 

operation
                  :load load :path path
                  :directory-operation 

directory-operation)
      (setf (aima-system-loaded? system) t))
     (t (warn "Unrecognized part: ~S in path ~A" part 

path)))))

(defun aima-file (name &key (type nil) (path nil))
  "Given a file name and maybe a file type and a relative 

path from the 
  AIMA directory, return the right complete pathname."
  (make-pathname :name name :type type :defaults *aima-

root*
         :directory (append (pathname-directory 

*aima-root*)
                    (mklist path))))

#-MCL ;; Macintosh Common Lisp already defines this 

function
(defun compile-load (file)
  "Compile file and then load it."
  ;; This could be made more sophisticated, to compile 

only when out of date.
  (compile-file (file-with-type file "lisp"))
  (load-binary file))

(defun load-binary (file)
  "Load file, trying the binary first, but loading the 

source if necessary."
  (load-something file '(binary nil "lisp")))

(defun load-something (file &optional (types '(nil binary 

"lisp")))
  "Try each of the types in turn until we get a file that 

loads.
  Complain if we can't find anything.  By default, try 

the system-dependent
  method first, then the binary, and finally the source 

(lisp) file."
  (dolist (type types (warn "Can't find file: ~A" file))
    (when (load (file-with-type file type) :if-does-not-

exist nil)
      (return t))))

(defun file-with-type (file type)
  "Return a pathname with the given type."
  (if (null type)
      file
    (merge-pathnames
     (make-pathname :type (if (eq type 'binary) *aima-

binary-type* type))
     file)))

(defun mklist (x)
  "If x is a list, return it; otherwise return a 

singleton list, (x)."
  (if (listp x) x (list x)))

;;; 

---------------------------------------------------------

-------------
;;;; Definitions of Systems
;;; 

---------------------------------------------------------

-------------

(def-aima-system utilities ()
  "Basic functions that are loaded every time, and used 

by many other systems."
  ("utilities" / "utilities" "binary-tree" "queue" 

"cltl2" "test-utilities"))

(def-aima-system agents (utilities)
  "Code from Part I: Agents and Environments"
  ("agents" / "test-agents"
   ("environments" / "basic-env" "grid-env" "vacuum" 

"wumpus")
   ("agents" / "agent" "vacuum" "wumpus")
   ("algorithms" / "grid")))

(def-aima-system search (agents)
  "Code from Part II: Problem Solving and Search"
  ("search" / "test-search" 
   ("algorithms" / "problems" "simple" "repeated" 
    "csp" "ida" "iterative" "sma" "minimax")
   ("environments" / "games" "prob-solve")
   ("domains" / "cannibals" "ttt" "cognac" "nqueens" 

"path-planning" 
    "puzzle8" "route-finding" "tsp" "vacuum")
   ("agents" / "ps-agents" "ttt-agent")))

(def-aima-system logic (agents)
  "Code from Part III: Logic, Inference, and Knowledge 

Representation"
   ("logic" / "test-logic"
    ("algorithms" / "tell-ask" "unify" "normal" "prop" 

"horn" "fol" "infix")
    ("environments" / "shopping")))

(def-aima-system planning ()
  "Code from Part IV: Planning and Acting"
   ("planning" / ))

(def-aima-system uncertainty (agents)
  "Code from Part V: Uncertain Knowledge and Reasoning"
  ("uncertainty" / "test-uncertainty"
   ("agents" / "mdp-agent")
   ("domains" / "mdp" "4x3-mdp")
   ("environments" / "mdp")
   ("algorithms" / "dp" "stats")))

(def-aima-system learning (uncertainty)
  "Code from Part VI: Learning"
   ("learning" / "test-learning"
    ("algorithms" / "inductive-learning" "learning-

curves" "dtl" "dll"
     "nn" "perceptron" "multilayer" "q-iteration")
    ("domains" / "restaurant-multivalued" "restaurant-

real"
     "restaurant-boolean" "majority-boolean" "ex-19-4-

boolean"
     "and-boolean" "xor-boolean" "4x3-passive-mdp")
    ("agents" / "passive-lms-learner" "passive-adp-

learner"
     "passive-td-learner" "active-adp-learner" "active-

qi-learner"
     "exploring-adp-learner" "exploring-tdq-learner")))

(def-aima-system language (logic)
  "Code from Part VII, Chapters 22-23: Natural Language 

and Communication"
   ("language" / "test-language"
    ("algorithms" / "chart-parse")
    ("domains" / "grammars" )))

(def-aima-system all ()
  "All systems except the utilities system, which is 

always already loaded"
  agents search logic planning uncertainty learning 

language)

(def-aima-system everything ()
  "All the code, including the utilities"
  utilities all)

(setf *aima-system-names* (nreverse *aima-system-names*))

;;;; Always load the utilities

(aima-load 'utilities)
```

This is the first time I've tried using lisp and I am having trouble finding the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not "Comma not inside a backquote", but the fact that you have edited line 9 wrong. Backslash escapes closing double quote, so your string does not end on line 9 and all the code becomes mess.

Only edit line 9 of the original file, try to do it this way:

```
(defparameter *aima-root* (truename "C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Lisp\\aima\\")
  "The root directory where the code is stored.")
```

Comment: @Aaron It's worth noting that this became rather evident using the syntax highlighting that Stack Overflow provides. Notice that `"C:\Users\Aaron\Lisp\" 

(truename "` is highlighted as a single string.  Are you using an editor without syntax highlighting?

Comment: @Joshua, I had downloaded Allegro-CL as suggested in the instructions. I've not used the software before but any attempt to open the lisp file either returned an error or just opened a new instance of Allegro. So I resorted to using notepad.... Won't be doing that again!

Comment: "any attempt to open the lisp file either returned an error or just opened a new instance of Allegro."  That seems like it might have been an appropriate Stack Overflow question.